# How do I run background code in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I am developing an app that should periodically fetch data from a remote source and save it locally, even if the app was not launched yet since the last boot.

Is it possible?

Comment: check if this plugin may help you (android only) https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

Comment: yep, to do this on Android you need a Service. And on iOS, you can't.